# How to auto check radio button basis of two radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

```html
 <div class="product_colors">     
        <span class="header" style="display:block;">Color</span>              
                             
          <label class="color_label active">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="gold" >Gold                           
          <span style="""></span>                  
          </label>
                         
          <label class="color_label">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="rose gold">Rose Gold                         
          <span style="" data-title="rose gold"></span>                  
          </label>
                        
          <label class="color_label">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="silver" > Silver                            
          <span style="" data-title="silver"></span>                  
          </label>                           
      </div>

      <div class="product_stones">
        <span class="header" style="display:block;">Stone</span>
           
        <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="malachite" >malachite         
        </label>          

        <label class="stone_label active">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="tiger-eye" > tiger-eye        
        </label>
          
        <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="black" > black           
        </label>

        <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="blue" > blue         
        </label>
          
      </div>

      <div class="combination">
          Combination
        <div class="hidden">             
            <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="malachite" data-handle="joory-earring-malachite-gold"> gold-malachite        
            <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="tiger-eye" data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold">gold-tiger-eye         
            <input type="radio" name="combination"  class="hidden_wrap" data-color="rose gold" data-stone="black" data-handle="kanz-ring-black-rose-gold"> rose-gold-black          
             <input type="radio" name="combination"  class="hidden_wrap" data-color="silver" data-stone="blue" data-handle="joory-earring-blue-silver"> silver-blue             
          
          </div>
      </div>
```

[here is my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emEjs.png)
I want to change combination radio button value to be select automatically on the basis of selected color and stone. Can someone help me to get rid of this problem.
Here is my code I've tried everything but I am new in *JS* so I can't find solution of this problem

Color              
                             
             
          Gold                           
                            
          
                         
             
          Rose Gold                         
                            
          
                        
             
           Silver

```
  <div class="product_stones">
    <span class="header" style="display:block;">Stone</span>
       
    <label class="stone_label">
      <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="malachite" >malachite         
    </label>          

    <label class="stone_label active">
      <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="tiger-eye" > tiger-eye        
    </label>
      
    <label class="stone_label">
      <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="black" > black           
    </label>

    <label class="stone_label">
      <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="blue" > blue         
    </label>
      
  </div>

  <div class="combination">
      Combination
    <div class="hidden">             
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="malachite" data-handle="joory-earring-malachite-gold"> gold-malachite        
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="tiger-eye" data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold">gold-tiger-eye         
        <input type="radio" name="combination"  class="hidden_wrap" data-color="rose gold" data-stone="black" data-handle="kanz-ring-black-rose-gold"> rose-gold-black          
         <input type="radio" name="combination"  class="hidden_wrap" data-color="silver" data-stone="blue" data-handle="joory-earring-blue-silver"> silver-blue             
      
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you show us your full html? from colour to combination?

Comment: see now i have uploaded again

Comment: by this logic there are total 12 combinations not the 4

Comment: it will generate msg not found if combination is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution I've tried which is not edit HTML.
My solution is going to find combination radio button that has proper `data-color` and `data-stone`

```js
$("input[name^='product_']").on('change', (e) => {
  $("input[name='combination']").prop('checked', false);
  var productColor = $("input[name='product_color']:checked").val();
  var productStone = $("input[name='product_stone']:checked").val();

  if (productColor !== undefined && productStone !== undefined) {
    if ($(`input[data-color='${productColor}'][data-stone='${productStone}']`).length) {
      $(`input[data-color='${productColor}'][data-stone='${productStone}']`).trigger('click');
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_colors">
  <span class="header" style="display:block;">Color</span>

  <label class="color_label active">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="gold" >Gold                           
          <span style="""></span>                  
          </label>

  <label class="color_label">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="rose gold">Rose Gold                         
          <span style="" data-title="rose gold"></span>                  
          </label>

  <label class="color_label">   
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" value="silver" > Silver                            
          <span style="" data-title="silver"></span>                  
          </label>
</div>

<div class="product_stones">
  <span class="header" style="display:block;">Stone</span>

  <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="malachite" >malachite         
        </label>

  <label class="stone_label active">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="tiger-eye" > tiger-eye        
        </label>

  <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="black" > black           
        </label>

  <label class="stone_label">
          <input type="radio" name="product_stone" value="blue" > blue         
        </label>

</div>

<div class="combination">
  Combination
  <div class="hidden">
    <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="malachite" data-handle="joory-earring-malachite-gold"> gold-malachite
    <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="gold" data-stone="tiger-eye" data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold">gold-tiger-eye
    <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="rose gold" data-stone="black" data-handle="kanz-ring-black-rose-gold"> rose-gold-black
    <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap" data-color="silver" data-stone="blue" data-handle="joory-earring-blue-silver"> silver-blue

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to disable radio button color and stone on the base of combination

Comment: sorry for my lateness, but I don't understand "on the base of combination". Could you please make an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need some jQuery to achieve this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.product_description').click(function() {
            var color = $('input[name="product_color"]:checked').val();
            var stone = $('input[name="product_stone"]:checked').val();
            var combinationClass = color + "-" + stone
            if ($('.' + combinationClass).length) {
                $('.' + combinationClass).attr('checked', true)
            } else {
                //If the class name of the combination is not found
                alert("something went wrong");
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<!--
   # Added common class for all the stone and colour radio buttons to enable trigger
   # Added Class based on the colour and stone value in the combination
   # Added checked attribute to stone and colour radio buttons for on Load default selection
-->
<div class="product_colors">
    <span class="header" style="display:block;">Color</span>
    <label class="color_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_color" value="gold" checked>Gold
        <span></span>
    </label>

    <label class="color_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_color" value="rose-gold">Rose Gold
        <span data-title="rose gold"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="color_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_color" value="silver"> Silver
        <span data-title="silver"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="product_stones">
    <span class="header" style="display:block;">Stone</span>

    <label class="stone_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_stone" value="malachite" checked>malachite
    </label>

    <label class="stone_label active">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_stone" value="tiger-eye"> tiger-eye
    </label>

    <label class="stone_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_stone" value="black"> black
    </label>

    <label class="stone_label">
        <input type="radio" class="product_description" name="product_stone" value="blue"> blue
    </label>

</div>

<div class="combination">
    Combination
    <div class="hidden">
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap gold-malachite" data-color="gold" data-stone="malachite" data-handle="joory-earring-malachite-gold"> gold-malachite
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap gold-toger-eye" data-color="gold" data-stone="tiger-eye" data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold">gold-tiger-eye
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap rose-gold-black" data-color="rose gold" data-stone="black" data-handle="kanz-ring-black-rose-gold"> rose-gold-black
        <input type="radio" name="combination" class="hidden_wrap silver-blue" data-color="silver" data-stone="blue" data-handle="joory-earring-blue-silver"> silver-blue

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to combine data attribute and then find the value

Comment: is it possible to find without adding combination class ?

Comment: you are going to need one selector in the combination radio to enable the checked attribute. you can use other ways as well i.e id, name

Comment: can i do it without combination class and combine data-attribute data-color and data stone?

Comment: Yes,  $('input[data-handle="{{value}}"]').attr('checked', true);